# socat: forward remote character device to local

Tags: linux, ssh, spi, socat

How to forward a character device from remote to local using `socat`?

I'm trying to use [URH](https://github.com/jopohl/urh) with an SPI (cc1101) device. My local computer has a lack of SPI Interface and my BananaPI can't run URH (at least I gave up after days of compiling)

My idea is to forward the SPI-Device to my local computer using `socat`. I did lots of tests but with no luck.

The 'easy' way terminates after 0.5 seconds. Is it possible to create a bidirectional listener? I searched around lots of time with no luck.

```sh
socat -d -d $HOME/dev/spidev0 EXEC:"ssh me@bananapi socat -d -d - /dev/spidev0.0"
```

```sh
bananapi:~:% ls -al /dev/spidev0.0          
crw-rw---- 1 root me 153, 0 Dez  7 23:54 /dev/spidev0.0
```

Comment: If character device uses ioctls, you can't. Socat doesn't provide ioctl calls forwarding, only data transpher. You should wrap SPI API into some higher level protocol.

Comment: Buy Diolan DLN2 USB/SPI adapter, much quicker and better solution (you will get GPIO and I2C as well).

Comment: Also read this: https://ez.analog.com/dsp/sigmadsp/f/q-a/98409/possibility-to-relay-the-spi-communication-over-the-network. Note you may spend 5 minutes googling for a such, no need to be bothered with SO.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Your question should remain strictly a question; you are welcome to post an actual answer to say that this is impossible, or else perhaps simply delete the question if you are no longer looking for an answer.